# How do I create an IF statement with words?

Tags: java, if-statement

Usually an if statement: `if(variable==60) {system.out.println("60");}`

BUT I want to test if `variable` was an exact match to a word.

For example the user enters into a text box 'hello'  How would I create an if statement that says if the user enters 'hello' system.out.println.... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

You need the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method :

```
if ("hello".equals(variable)) {
```

Note that there is also a [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) method, which may be useful if the user may enter "Hello" instead of "hello".

It is often a good idea to test with "hello" first so that if variable is null you will not get a `NullPointerException`. If variable is null then the if returns false.

Comment: I am trying to make a program that allows a user to type in a name, then the name is ticked of the database(array) of names.

Answer (score 3):

Many people usually get confused with this because they try to use `==` on strings (which are objects), and receive unexpected results. You will have to use `if ("hello".equals(var)) {...}`. Bear in mind that the `equals` method is for objects, and `==` is generally for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear example:

```
    String pool1 = "funny";
    String pool2 = "funny";
    String not_pooled = new String("funny");
    System.out.println("pool1 equals pool2 ? "+(pool1==pool2)); //Equal because they point to same pooled instance
    System.out.println("pool1 equals not_pooled ? "+(pool1==not_pooled)); //Not equal because 'not_pooled' not pooled.
    System.out.println("pool1 equals not_pooled ? " +(pool1.equals(not_pooled))); //Equal because the contents of the object is checked and not the reference
```

Output:

pool1 equals pool2 ? true

pool1 equals not_pooled ? false

pool1 equals not_pooled ? true